# Oracle SQL value for repeated item

Tags: sql, oracle

We have a list of orders that have multiple items, request is to have a value for each of the individual set of IDs. Like this:

```
order_id    id_number
ABC123      1
ABC123      1
DEF456      2
DEF456      2
DEF456      2
DEF456      2
GHI987      3
```

So that way we get a single number for each of the order_ids (and thus they can order the list using the id_number column).
Customer wants this to have an 'easier' view due to the amount of times an order can be repeated.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a good use case for `DENSE_RANK`:

```
SELECT order_id, 
DENSE_RANK () 
  OVER (ORDER BY order_id) AS id_number 
FROM orders;
```

Try out: [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/Aiq6Hx65)

Note: This answer assumes you are showing the expected outcome in your question because I understand it this way. If this is wrong, please make your question clear(er).

Answer (score 1):

```
select   ORDER_ID
        ,ID_NUMBER
        ,count(*) as ORDER_COUNT
from     t
group by ORDER_ID, ID_NUMBER
```

| ORDER_ID | ID_NUMBER | ORDER_COUNT |
| --- | --- | --- |
| ABC123 | 1 | 2 |
| DEF456 | 2 | 4 |
| GHI987 | 3 | 1 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/vofHocus)